# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

so i faced strange behaviour with this code below. I am getting error that local variable `flag` is referenced before assignment, but its assigned at the top as global variable. Can someone tell me whats going here and why `flag` is not incrementing as expected?

```
import concurrent.futures


flag = 0
def make_some():
    try:
        flag += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    tasks = {
        executor.submit(
            make_some
        ): task_id
        for task_id in [1,2,3]
    }
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        pass
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you have to use **global** keyword to solve this problem

read more here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/global-keyword-in-python

so without global , every variable is only in the local scope as if there was no global variable defined and hence the error

once you use the **global** keyword, then in the inner scope python acknowledges the presence of a **global** variable definition

Comment: The `global` is required only for re-assigning a global variable inside a inner scope. You can always read a global variable from inner scope if non of the local variables have a clashing name (which is what's happening here)

Answer (score 1):

This should work (adding `global`):

```
import concurrent.futures


flag = 0
def make_some():

    global flag  # <--- USE GLOBAL

    try:
        flag += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    tasks = {
        executor.submit(
            make_some
        ): task_id
        for task_id in [1,2,3]
    }
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        pass
```

Comment: May you explain why `global` is needed?